# How to return values from async functions using async-await from function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, axios

How can I return the value from an async function?
I tried to like this

```
const axios = require('axios');
async function getData() {
    const data = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    return data;
}
console.log(getData());
```

it returns me this,

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

Comment: console.log(await getData());

(if this code is another function, then it need to be marked as async as well)

Comment: or treat this as a Promise, and do it the 'old' way : `getData().then(x => { console.log(x); } )`

Comment: @pac0: That does not return a value, which is what the question is about.

Comment: In the developer console the following works `async function getData() {return await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');}` followed by just `await getData()`.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

You cant `await` something outside `async` scope. To get expected result you should wrap your `console.log` into async IIFE i.e

```
async function getData() {
  return await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
}

(async () => {
  console.log(await getData())
})()
```

[`Working`](https://jsfiddle.net/vfjzkerj/232/) sample.

More information about [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/async_function)

Since `axios` returns a promise the `async/await` can be omitted for the `getData` function like so:

```
function getData() {
  return axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
}
```

and then do same as we did before

```
(async () => {
   console.log(await getData())
})()
```

Comment: (async () => {
  console.log(await getData())
})()  what's going on here?

Comment: are you running a annonymous async function. right?

Comment: but you can use another 'named' function instead, if you need.

Comment: @KingRayhan You're right, an anonymous async function is being invoked in place. Such anonymous function are called Immediately Invoked Function Expressions (IIFEs) in JS.

Comment: "To get expected result you should wrap your console.log into async IIFE i.e" is now outdated, we have top level await in most JS environments.

Answer (score 39):

your function getData will return a Promise.

So you can either:

- `await` the function as well to get the result. However, to be able to use `await`, you need to be in an `async` function, so you need to 'wrap' this:

  ```js
  async function callAsync() {
     var x = await getData();
     console.log(x);
  }
  callAsync();
  ```

  (I named the function for sake of clarity, but in this scenario, one would rather use an anonymous function call; see TheReason's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49938734/1454514).)

or

- use the result as a normal Promise, which is what an async function returns.
  You have to use `then` with a callback:

  ```js
  getData().then(x => { 
      console.log(x); 
  });
  ```

Answer (score 23):

The other answers have covered this fine; but I'd like to chip in and say get in the habit of creating and calling a `main` function rather than run things in the global scope. i.e.

```
async function main(){
  let result = await getData();
}

main().catch(console.log);
```

This is pretty clear to anyone reading your code that this is your *app entry point*

Comment: Thanks - this is the best approach, imho, and helped me realize why I couldn't call an async method defined in a clasa at the root of a node module