# NodeJS use async/ await instead of Promise for Wordpos

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I started doing NLP operation for a NodeJS app; The idea is to analyze some text and classify words as a verb, adjective, adverb, etc.

I found `wordpos` and it responds completely to my needs:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/wordpos

I am trying to create a process function to create a keyword list using Wordpos.

My code is:

```
let content = lines.map(line => {
   let element = line.split("=");
   return {
      name: element[0],
      content: element[1],
      keyword: process(element[1])
   }
});
```

All functions of Wordpos require a callback. Promises can be used too to do some functions chaining. I understand that its operations need to hit wordnet-db so it works is async. Or I need to make sync calls and get results before going to the next steps of my code.

```
wordpos.getPOS(text, console.log);
{
  nouns:[],        
  verbs:[],        
  adjectives:[],  
  adverbs:[],     
  rest:[]          
}
```

I tried to create `async/ await` calls but it's not working:

```
async function f(text) {
   return await wordpos.getPOS(text);
}
console.log(f('The angry bear chased the frightened little squirrel'));
```

And result is:

> node api_data.js
>
> Promise {  }

Comment: Hey welcome to SO! Do you mind editing your question a bit to make it more clear what exactly you are asking?

Comment: You can't do async things in a sync way. You have to deal with that ...

Comment: check this answer, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49938266/how-to-return-values-from-async-functions-using-async-await-from-function/49938734#49938734), this is similar to your case