# getting a return value out of an async expression

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I get a return value from the following code? I don't want to just console log it

```
function get_disk_space(callback){
    checkDiskSpace('C:\\').then((diskSpace) => {
      var free = Math.floor(diskSpace.free/1000000000)
      var size = Math.floor(diskSpace.size/1000000000)
      var used = size - free
      percent = (size - free)
      percent = percent/size*100
      percent = Math.floor(percent)+'%'
      return percent;
    });
  }
```

running this will return undefined while running a console log just before return percent will give me the correct answer..

Comment: Since it’s async the return statement will go to the next `then()` statement, which you don’t have. Instead of returning you could call a function that has the rest of your code that handles the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a `then`-handler to process the resolved value, e.g:

```
function get_disk_space(callback) {
    return checkDiskSpace('C:\\').then((diskSpace) => {
        var free = Math.floor(diskSpace.free / 1000000000)
        var size = Math.floor(diskSpace.size / 1000000000)
        var used = size - free
        percent = (size - free)
        percent = percent / size * 100
        percent = Math.floor(percent) + '%'
        return percent;
    });
}
```

In order to access the result outside the get_disk_space function scope, you need to do:

```
get_disk_space().then((result) => {
   //log and handle your result
   console.log(result);
   // handle your result
});
```

In case the function where you call `get_disk_space` is async, you can simply do:

```
async function testFunc() {
const result = await get_disk_space();
// handle result
}
```

Comment: still cant take the result outside the scope though.. I want to save it as a variable not log it

Comment: Maybe also check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49938266/how-to-return-values-from-async-functions-using-async-await-from-function

Comment: tried both you'r solutions, still returns undefined :/l

Comment: its just console.log(get_disk_space());