# What does this statement in javascript/nodejs mean? in terms of the significance of => operator and the async, await keywords here?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

(1) this is apparently code that hashes a password. however what does it exactly do syntactically? why does it use async and await this way? and => does not seem to define a function.

`const hashPassword = async password => await bcrypt.hash(password, 10)`

(2) how do you return a value in an async function? i have an async function returning an array however when called it is received as a Promise object..

```
async function agentname() { 
  // ...
  return an_array;
}

let data = agentname();
console.log("in callback. data is " + data);
```

Output:

```
in callback. data is [object Promise]
```

Is the problem in how i define the function/return value or how the function is called?

Comment: "*and => does not seem to define a function*" why do you say that? `async password => await bcrypt.hash(password, 10)` is an async arrow function that takes a parameter `password` and returns `bcrypt.hash(password, 10)` after awaiting the result. Presumably, `bcrypt.hash` is also async.

Comment: `i have an async function returning an array however when called it is received as a Promise object` that's what async functions always do - they are supposed to be asynchronous, so the result will come *at a later time*. They always return a Promise. You either `await` it or use the promise API and use `.then` on it.

Comment: i see. i expected parenthesis to be around the parameters in this form of definition.. ok so if this is a function then the placement of await makes sense. (i am fairly new to javascript. )

Comment: In arrow functions, if you have a single parameter, you can omit the brackets around it: `(arg) => arg + 1` is the same as `arg => arg + 1`. If you have zero or more than one parameters, then you cannot omit them: ` => 1` is invalid by itself, you need `() => 1` also (arg1, arg2) => arg1 + arg2` cannot be written as `arg1, arg2 => arg1 + arg2` (technically, its valid syntax but has different semantics)

Comment: using `await` would mean preceding the call with `await` and preceding the defining function with `async`? that seemed to work. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> this is apparently code that hashes a password. however what does it exactly do syntactically? why does it use async and await this way? and => does not seem to define a function.

It **does** define a function and assigns `hashPassword` to the function. It's the same thing as this:

```
const hashPassword = async function( password ) {
    return await bcrypt.hash( password, 10 );
};
```

...or this (just to be clear):

```
const hashPassword = async function( password ) {
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash( password, 10 );
    return hashedPassword;
};
```

and also largely (for the most part) the same thing as doing this:

```
async function hashPassword( password ) {
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash( password, 10 );
    return hashedPassword;
}
```

...which is the same thing as this (ignoring error-handling with `rej`):

```
function hashPassword( password ) {
    return new Promise( ( res, rej ) => bcrypt.hash( password, 10 ).then( h => res( h ) )
}
```

> how do you return a value in an async function? i have an async function returning an array however when called it is received as a Promise object..

When a function is annotated with `async` it wraps the return value in a `Promise<T>`. Because of how types change behind-the-scenes when using `async` functions in JavaScript I strongly recommend using TypeScript instead of JavaScript to avoid errors like these. Note that you can use `await` with both Promise and non-Promise functions, at least.

In JavaScript, these two functions are equivalent:

```
async function foo() {
    const v = await anotherAsyncFunction();
    return v;
}

function foo() {
    return new Promise( function(resolve,reject) {
        anotherAsyncFunction().then( v => resolve( v ) );
    } );
}
```

When a function returns a `Promise<T>` can you can either `await` it to get `T` or you use a `then` function.

See here: [How to return values from async functions using async-await from function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49938266/how-to-return-values-from-async-functions-using-async-await-from-function)