# Why is State always empty?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I have thoroughly gone through all the asked question and none of them apply to my problem directly. I am looping through an array of user ids and matching them to get a user from my firestore db. I get the result back with no problem but when i store it in the state array and run a console log, my state array is always empty. The first console.log works and shows the results from the db.

Here's my code:

```
const UsersScreen = (props) => {

    const [state, setState] = useState({
        users: []
    });  

    const getUserProfiles = () => {
        let users = [];
        //networkUsers is an array with the ids
        networkUsers.forEach(userId => { 
            db.doc(userId).get().then((doc) => {
                users.push(doc.data());
                console.log('localusers', users)
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log('caught error', error)
            })
        });

        setState({ users: users });
    };


    useEffect(() => {
        getUserProfiles();
    }, []);

console.log('state', state.users)
}
```

Please help.

Comment: I’d recommend not using an object inside useState.

Comment: you need to access `state.users`, not `users.push()`
and use Spread operator to insert your data
and also its better to change `state` and `setState` to different names

Comment: Is `db.doc().get()` asynchronous?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes it is. What's your reasoning behind not using objects inside useState?

Comment: @zb22 i’m doing this because id rather not setState inside a forloop

Comment: Mainly in useEffects the dependency array does reference equality. So an object makes it harder to use.

Comment: If the doc call is async then you need to wait for it. This is async 101.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return values from async functions using async-await from function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49938266/how-to-return-values-from-async-functions-using-async-await-from-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic that fetches the document from Firestore is asynchronous. The call to `setState` is synchronous though. It will always **before** the document has been fetched. The solution would be to fetch the documents **then** set the state. Here is an example:

```
const UsersScreen = (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    users: [],
  });

  const getUserProfiles = () => {
    Promise.all(networkUsers.map((userID) => db.doc(userId).get()))
      .then((docs) => {
        setState({ users: docs.map((doc) => doc.data()) });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("caught error", error);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserProfiles();
  }, []);

  console.log("state", state.users);
};
```

The `Promise.all` call resolves once every user has been fetched from the Firestore (maybe you could fetch them at once though). Once we have the users we loop over them with `map` to extract the data of the document and set the state. Here is an alternative with `async/await`:

```
const UsersScreen = (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    users: [],
  });

  const getUserProfiles = async () => {
    try {
      const docs = await Promise.all(
        networkUsers.map((userID) => db.doc(userId).get())
      );

      setState({ users: docs.map((doc) => doc.data()) });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("caught error", error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserProfiles();
  }, []);

  console.log("state", state.users);
};
```

Comment: This works. Can the same be done in a async await function?

Comment: @abdi Yes, you can use `for await...of` in order to use async await, 
but then you will need to `setState` for each iteration, so `Promise.all` would be much better
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of

Comment: Yes async/await is possible. I've updated the example with this alternative.