# Why this function is not returning any value inside connection.query?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

function x() is supposed to return result variable but it is returning undefined also console.log(result) is printing on the terminal. Also return test1 is showing undefined but return test2 is returning correctly.

```js
const mysql = require("mysql");

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'p_two',
    port: '3306'
});

connection.connect((error) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
    else {
        console.log("Mysql connected")
    }
});

function x() {
    const con = connection.query("SELECT * FROM blog WHERE id = 1", (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
        else {
            console.log(results)
            return results
        };
        // return "test1"
    });
    // return "test2"
}

console.log(x())
```

Comment: The only `return` statement in `x` is commented out. The `return` statement in the anonymous function you pass to `query` is not in `x`, it is in the anonymous function.

Comment: I do not find that question duplicate.

Comment: But your comment is somehow useful, still dont understand the solution.

Comment: "I do not find that question duplicate" — Well, it is.  And the solutions are explained in 105 different ways on it.

Comment: Okay, I thought that question is related to Ajex but mine is Mysql. I am reading that question. THanks

Comment: Asynchronously called callbacks are asynchronously called callbacks no matter if they are playing with HTTP, databases or something else.

Comment: I tried some methods but I am not good in javascript, and don't know how to implement async/await in this case. Terminal is now showing Promise { <pending> }

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49938266/how-to-return-values-from-async-functions-using-async-await-from-function