# Ajax Function is Returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I have this block of code that returns `access_token` for login

```js
async function login(username, password) {
  await $.ajax({
    url: "/api/login",
    type: "POST",
    data: `{"username": "${username}", "password": "${password}"}`,
    dataType: "text",

    success: async function(response) {
      var a = await JSON.parse(response)
      console.log(a.token.access_token)
      return a.token.access_token
    },

    error: function(response) {
      return "false"
    }
  })
}
```

It is returning

```sh
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdXRob3JpemVkIjp0cnVlLCJleHAiOjE2MTgzODIzNzUsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoic2sxMTIyIn0.e16nHpJUsNmMSAcPgaHkmJgwrnBkp4jB7KHe_ylAvKc // console.log() from login()

undefined // console.log() in another function
```

```js
console.log(await login(questions[0].value, questions[2].value))
```

Am I wrong in Using Async/Await? or is it something else?

Comment: Why are you using `await` on `JSON.parse`? It is a synchronous function

Comment: @TrevorKropp Also the await in the login function.

Comment: @TrevorKropp I was trying different things, BTW I am new to JS World. So I didn't know that but Thanks for telling

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return values from async functions using async-await from function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49938266/how-to-return-values-from-async-functions-using-async-await-from-function)

Comment: Ya, Thanks @freedomn-m

Answer (score 2):

- You need to use the Promise semantics of `$.ajax()`, the `success` callback will not work for return values.
- You need to `return` the promise from the `$.ajax()` call.
- Absolutely nothing inside your `login()` function needs to be `async` or `await`.

Correct code:

```
function login(username, password) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: "/api/login",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      username: username,
      password: password
    },
    dataType: "text"
  }).then(function (response) {
    var data = JSON.parse(response);
    return data.token.access_token;
  }).fail(function (jqXhr, status, error) {
    return false;
  });
}
```

and

```
console.log(await login(questions[0].value, questions[2].value));
```

---

It makes no sense to set `dataType: "text"` when you're expecting JSON from the server. Set the `Content-Type: application/json` header in your server response, drop the `dataType` parameter, and jQuery will even automatically parse the JSON for you.

```
function login(username, password) {
  return $.post("/api/login", {username: username, password: password})
    .then((data) => data.token.access_token)
    .fail((jqXhr, status, error) => false);
}
```

If you want, you *can* turn that into an `async`/`await` based function:

```
function login(username, password) {
  try {
    const data = await $.post("/api/login", {username: username, password: password});
    return data.token.access_token;
  } catch (err) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it Worked. I think it is because we are also returning ajax call so it will wait? is it correct?

Comment: @SatyamKulkarni In principle, yes - any function call that is supposed to work with `await` needs to return a Promise. So if you want to make your `login()` function `await`able, it needs to return a Promise. `$.ajax()` produces a promise, so return it. But *if* you're returning a Promise, then useing `await` inside of the `login()` function is not necessary anymore. It's enough when your code waits in one place for the result, and that place is the line where you use `await login(...)`.