# Returned data from function is Promise (fulfilled) data

Tags: javascript, promise

```
defaultValue = getFile(getCurrent.value[name])
```

Function getFile:

```
const getFile = async (id) => {
  const data = store.dispatch(Actions.FILE, id).then(() => {
    const data = [{ description: store.getters.currentFile.description, url: 'https://test.com/uploads/'+ store.getters.currentFile.name }]
    return data
  })
  return data
}
```

If I console.log(defaultValue): I see the following output; [image]

But I need a array instead of this Promise thing. How to solve?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49938266/7785337

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `await` keyword on your `getFile` to retrieve value front promise because your getFile returns Promise.

```
async function yourFunc() {
   defaultValue = await getFile(getCurrent.value[name])
   // do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: This will make no difference... the code inside `getFile` never waits for the response to be received and nothing is ever `await`ed within it

Comment: @Jamiec The current code inside `getFile` is returning a Promise that resolves to an array of objects, so the code witihn getFile itself doesn't need to wait for the response, as the Promise being returned will be notified/resolve when the response is received, so this code should work without changing `getFile`

Comment: @NickParsons you're absolutely right.. the thrice reuse of the variable `data` confused me

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `await` keyword

```
const getFile = async (id) => {
   await store.dispatch(Actions.FILE, id);
   return  [{ description: store.getters.currentFile.description, url: 'https://test.com/uploads/'+ store.getters.currentFile.name }]
}
```

and then await the call to `getFile` too

```
defaultValue = await getFile(getCurrent.value[name])
```