# Function does not pass object to the constant

Tags: javascript, string, object

I'm new to javascript so maybe it's a dumb mistake. I'm trying to pass the values ​​of the object that I get in this webscrapping function to the constant but I'm not succeeding. Every time I try to print the menu it prints as "undefined".
`

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function getMenu() {
    console.log("Opening the browser...");
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://pra.ufpr.br/ru/ru-centro-politecnico/', {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
    console.log("Content loaded...");

    // Get the viewport of the page
    const fullMenu = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return {
            day: document.querySelector('#conteudo div:nth-child(3) p strong').innerText,
            breakfastFood: document.querySelector('tbody tr:nth-child(2)').innerText,
            lunchFood: document.querySelector('tbody tr:nth-child(4)').innerText,
            dinnerFood: document.querySelector('tbody tr:nth-child(6)').innerText
        };
    });

    await browser.close();
    
    return {
        breakfast: fullMenu.day + "\nCafé da Manhã:\n" + fullMenu.breakfastFood,
        lunch:     fullMenu.day + "\nAlmoço:\n" + fullMenu.lunchFood,
        dinner:    fullMenu.day + "\nJantar:\n" + fullMenu.dinnerFood
    };
};

const menu = getMenu();
console.log(menu.breakfast);
```

`

I've tried to pass these values ​​in several ways to a variable but I'm not succeeding. I also accept other methods of passing these strings, I'm doing it this way because it's the simplest I could think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your getMenu() is an async function.

In your last bit of code, can you change it to,

```
(async () => {
   let menu = await getMenu();
   console.log(menu.breakfast);
})();
```

credit to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49938266/how-to-return-values-from-async-functions-using-async-await-from-function).

Comment: When I try to put the await in front this error appears. SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Comment: @João I have updated the answer and ran it on my machine, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I have no access to the package that you imported. You may try changing the last part of your code to:

```
const menu = await getMenu();
if (menu) {
    console.log(menu.breakfast);
 }
```

**Explanation**

`getMenu()` and `await getMenu()` are different things in JS. `getMenu()` is a [Promise Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which does not represent any string / number / return value. `await getMenu()` tells JS to run other code first to wait for the result of `getMenu()`.

Despite `await` tells JS to wait for `getMenu()` to be resolved, it doesn't stop `console.log(menu.breakfast)` from running. Your code will try to access `menu` - which at that moment it is a Promise object. Therefore, `breakfast` property doesn't exist in the Promise object, so you get `undefined`.

By adding a `if (menu) {...}` statement, javascript will wait until `menu` is resolved before going inside the if-statement. This is useful when you want to do `console.log()` on a async/await return value.

Comment: When I try to put the await in front this error appears. SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules