# How to import conditionally a JSON file and return a key?

Tags: node.js, promise

Considering a simple function that should load a `.json` file dynamically and conditionally, then return a specific key from this file as below:

```
export const translate = async (key: string, from: string) =>
  await import(`../locales/www/${from}.json`)
    .then((translations) => {
      const translation = translations.default[key];
      console.log(translation);      // console.log() works
      // Promise.resolve(translation);
      return translation;            // returns a promise object not the value
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));



// In another file
translate(a, b)
```

I can't understand why it doesn't return a value (wanted behaviour) but a Promise.

Comment: Because it's an async function. They _always_ return promises.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return values from async functions using async-await from function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49938266/how-to-return-values-from-async-functions-using-async-await-from-function)

Answer (score 1):

- Async functions always returns `Promise`, to extract its value you have to call with `await` ( `await translate(a, b)`).
- JSON import using `import` is a very new feature and not available in older versions of node.
- Never call Promises with `await` or `.then` simultaneously

```js
import fs from 'fs/promises'
import path from 'path'

const __dirname = path.dirname(new URL(import.meta.url).pathname)

export const translate = async (key: string, from: string) => {
  try {
    const translationsFile = await fs.readFile(path.join( __dirname, `../locales/www/${from}.json`))
    const translations =  JSON.parse(translationsFile)
    return translations[key] 
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    return 
  }
}


// another file
// const value = await translate(<key>, <from>)
```

Comment: your file path becomes invalid. it's now relative to process.cwd(), not to the module file

Answer (score 0):

Some notices:

1. avoid using `.then()` whenever possible. this will make your life easier
2. seems your json file isn't json but js. because if you import json in node your way it will throw `ERR_IMPORT_ASSERTION_TYPE_MISSING`. You should assert or read the json file manually and resolve relative paths yourself using `import.meta.url`.
3. you shouldn't use `await` for return values because it blocks execution of the caller. the caller should decide itself what to do with the returned promise, wait or continue.
4. move your `catch` to the caller, it knows better what to do with the error. otherwise you just usually rethrow it.
5. since you're using an async function you should use `await` when using it.

So on my node 18 this works fine:

```
export const translate = async (key, from) => {
    const { default: translations } = await import(`../locales/www/${from}.json`, { assert: { type: 'json' } });
    return translations[key];
}
```

usage:

```
await translate(key, from);
```