# Not able to get value set inside foreach

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a foreach loop, where I am creating an object. I am able to get that object inside forEach loop, but not able to get outside loop. Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
   let errorObj
   let versionError 
   Object.keys(myObj).forEach(async function (name) {
       let dataStr = await getData(name)
       if(dataStr!==''){
         versionError.push(dataStr)
         errorObj = JSON.stringify(versionError)
       }
       console.log(errorObj) //getting object 
     })
    console.log(errorObj) //not getting object
```

Comment: `let` means the variable is scoped to within the function. You'll need to save it to a more globally scope variable to access it outside of the function.

Comment: Here is the [documentation for let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).

Comment: Even with a more global scope as suggested above, you'll still run into a problem because of the `async` `forEach`. You may want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49938266/how-to-return-values-from-async-functions-using-async-await-from-function

Comment: I have declared versionError and errorObj outside forEach loop

Comment: @jnpdx I think this would solve my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official documentation suggests not to use forEach with async/await.
( https://plainenglish.io/blog/async-await-foreach )

I have changed the forEach function with for, and it worked for me.

```
const getVersionError = async() => {
   for await (let name of Object.keys(zipData.files)){
     let dataStr = await getData(name)
     if(dataStr!==''){
       versionError.push(dataStr)
       errorObj = JSON.stringify(versionError
     }
   }
   return versionError
}
```