# Problem with setTimeout when sending Graphql mutation in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gqlquery

I had this problem.
I need to divide the values from one form into two parts and send them to one address.

**graphql**

```
mutation calc($applicationRecipientsFilter: ApplicationRecipientsFilterInput) {    
    create(applicationRecipientsFilter: $applicationRecipientsFilter) {
        id
        city {
            id
            name    
        }
        applicationType    
        recipients      
    }
}
```

**hooks**

```js
const { mutate } = useMutation(calc);

const addNewNotification = useCallback( 
    async (args) => { 
        try { 
            const { error } = await mutate(args); 
            if (error) { 
                console.log(error)
                return; 
            } 
        } catch (e) { 
            console.log(e)
        } 
    }, 
    [mutate], 
);
```

**component**

```js
const handleAddNotification = useCallback(() => { 
    const { city, email, email2 } = values; // values from useFormik();
    const currentCity = citiesOption.find(({ value }) => value === city); 

    const createArguments = (applicationType, recipients) => ({ 
        applicationRecipients: { 
            city: { 
                name: currentCity?.label, 
                id: currentCity?.value, 
            }, 
            applicationType, 
            recipients, 
        }, 
    }); 

    addNewNotification(createArguments(creditTypeOption[0]?.value, email)); 

    setTimeout(() => addNewNotification(createArguments(creditTypeOption[1]?.value, email2)), 1500); 
}, [addNewNotification, creditTypeOption, values, citiesOption]);
```

Why, if setTimeout is used, everything is successfully sent? If you don't use it, you just get cancelled status and nothing in the response And what other ways are there to rewrite the code without using setTimeout?

```js
addNewNotification(createArguments(creditTypeOption[0]?.value, email)); 
addNewNotification(createArguments(creditTypeOption[1]?.value, email2)),
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: `await` keyword or `.then` function.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49938356